# Port of current call in Remoting

Tags: .net, remoting, port

There can be several instances of my service on the same computer, each of them on a different port.

How can I retrieve the port number from which the current request came through to differentiate them?

To clarify, if client is calling the following method:

```
class OrdersService : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void EnqueueOrder(Order order)
    {
        //int port = ??
    }
}
```

I need the port number from which the request was made.

PS: I tried implementing the IServerChannelSink interface but it can only access the URI (like /foo/bar) and IP address of the client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you require to call back to the client, then that should be a part of your contract:

```
public void EnqueueOrder(Order order, IClient client)
{
  // Work with the order.

  // Call back to the client.
}
```

On the client side, you would implement the IClient interface with a class that derives from MarshalByRefObject, and pass that to the EnqueueOrder method.

Answer (score 0):

This is heinous, and not very generalized, but should work for you:

```
TcpChannel       channel = (TcpChannel)ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels[0];
ChannelDataStore data    = (ChannelDataStore)channel.ChannelData;
string           uri     = data.ChannelUris[0];
int              port    = int.Parse(uri.Substring(uri.LastIndexOf(':')));
```

Note that you'll need a reference to System.Runtime.Remoting.dll and you'll need `using`s for `System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels`, and `System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp`.

Of course, if you have more than one channel registered, and/or it's not TCP, and/or you have more than one URI for the channel, then you'll have to write better code than the hack-job I did above, but it should give you the idea, anyway.

---

How are these separate server instances started, anyway?  How is the port selected in the first place?  How does the client discover the port?  The answers to these questions may reveal a more ideal method for distinguishing the instance within the server's code, such as an instance identifier passed on the command line.